# how do I polymorph two classes into one

Tags: polymorphism

hi i have two classes, example: ftp1 (handles normal ftp stuff), ftp2 (handles secure ftp connections, and stuff). based on a configuration setting I need to instantiate a type that can be one of these two types as a class level variable. Is this possible, if so, can someone point me in the right direction. I've tried to apply polymorphism to this situation, but I'm a little confused as to how to do that?

Comment: side note: I don't have control over the two ftp classes. they are part of a third party framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two FTP classes are part of a third-party framework (and do not already implement a common base class), you have two options:

**Wrap the classes in a new class, which implements a common base class or interface**

```
//Interface for original library classes.
public someClass {
    public void DoSomething();
}

public someClass2 {
    public void DoSomething();
}

//Wrapper implementation
public wrappedSomeClass : baseSomeClass {
    private someClass mSomeClass;

    public wrappedSomeClass() {
        mSomeClass = new someClass();
    }

    //DoSomething will need to be defined in baseSomeClass
    public overrides void DoSomething() {
        mSomeClass.DoSomething();
    }
}

public wrappedSomeClass2 : baseSomeClass {
    private someClass2 mSomeClass2;

    public wrappedSomeClass2() {
        mSomeClass2 = new someClass2();
    }

    //DoSomething will need to be defined in baseSomeClass
    public overrides void DoSomething() {
        mSomeClass2.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Once the wrappers are written, you write your new code using the wrapper classes.

**Store the values in a variable of type `Object`**

The `object` data type is the common base for all classes. Your code would look like this:

```
public someclass {
    private object myVariable;
    private void somemethod() {
        if(something) {
            myVariable = new something();
        } else {
            myvariable = new something2();
        }
    }
}
```

When you use the value of the variable, you will almost always need to cast it back to its original type.

```
if(something) {
    ((something)myVariable).InvokeMethod();
} else {
    ((something2)myVariable).InvokeMethod();
}
```

Comment: the second option definitely works, and is easiest to implement, but still ties me to knowing what type i am using instead of being able to just use myvariable.invokemethod();

Comment: @danielea Then option one is the way you'll want to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using interfaces. With the following code you need to make the receiving method accept an instance of a class which implements iftp.

```
interface iftp {
  string address;
  int port;
  void SomeMethod();
}


class ftp1 : iftp {
  void SomeMethod() {
    /* implement regular ftp logic */
  }
}

class ftp2 : iftp {
  void SomeMethod() {
    /* implement secure ftp logic */
  }
}
```

Comment: what if the two classes are part of a 3rd party framework and I don't have control over their implementation? basically, i just want to be able to do the following:


public someclass
{
  private (polymorphedType) myVariable;

  private void somemethod()
  {
     if(something)
     {
        myVariable = new something();
     }
     else
     {
        myvariable = new something2();
     }
   }
}

Comment: @danielea Intresting ... i would probably go for something like passing parameter of type object and try to figure out what type it is when i need it with typeof(classname) == parameter.GetType().

Comment: I tried to do something similiar, i think, to what you are suggesting, but couldn't get it to work. can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Two options stick out to me and which to use changes depending on the situation:

- **BaseClass with InheritedClassess**

  - If `ftp1` and `ftp2` share common functionality but extend that functionality in unique ways, you could use a base class with several implementing subclasses.  This way, you can have other properties and methods in your program that expect the base class and have access to common properties.

.

```
public abstract class FtpBase {
    public string ConnectionInformation
    public int TimeoutSeconds
}

public class ftp1 : FtpBase {
    public void MakeConnectionToFTPServer() {...}
}

public class ftp2 : FtpBase {
    public void MakeSecureConnectionToFTPSever() {...}
}
```

- **Interfaces**

  - Another option is to use interfaces, where you define what you expect the implementing classes to have.  You can still tell other properties and methods to expect the interface as a parameter or property type; as long as the passed object implements the interface, it will be able to work.  The consume code doesn't care what the object is as long as it implements the interface.

.

```
public interface IFtp {
    public void MakeConnection()
}

public class ftp1 : IFtp {
    public void MakeConnection (){...code to make a regular connection}
}

public class ftp2 : IFtp {
    public void MakeConnection (){...code to make a secure connection}
}

//Then you might have in some other code:

public void ConnectViaFtp(IFtp ftp) {
     ftp.MakeConnection()   // the code doesn't know if this is ftp1 or 
                            // ftp2. All it cares about is calling
                            // MakeConnection().
}
```

If both ftp classes are expected to have the same functionality with different implementations, I would use `interfaces`.  However, if each ftp class shares only some of the same properties and methods (where the functionality of the methods in each implementation is the same) but *extends* common functionality uniquely between the two, you might use `BaseClass with InheritedClasses`.  You can also use a combination of the two, depending on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that interfaces define what something does, and implementation defines how it does it.

So, in your case, define an ftp interface that defined the actions you want - logging in, getting a file listing, putting a file getting a file, disconnecting etc.

The create two implementations, one for normal ftp, one for secure. You may find it useful to create a 'base' ftp implemtation with general processing that is extended by the two specific derivatives.

So you have:

ftp interface - containing method declarations for provided fuinctionality

baseftp abstract class - implementation of ftp interface, calling defined abstract methods for secure or non-secure specific actions

secureftp concrete class - implements abstract methods defined in baseftp for a secure connection

insecureftp concrete class - implements abstract methods defined in baseftp for a nonsecure connection

Comment: thanks visage, you are correct however what if the two classes are part of a 3rd party framework and I don't have control over their implementation? basically, i just want to be able to do the following: public someclass { private (polymorphedType) myVariable; private void somemethod() { if(something) { myVariable = new something(); } else { myvariable = new something2(); } } }

Comment: Then you should use composition and delegation. In your concrete class delegate method calls to an appropriate instance of the third party library

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can implement a Factory Mehod Patther or a simple Strategy method one. PLase take a look at this code examples at

[Factory Method Pattern](http://dofactory.net/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx)

[Strategy Pattern](http://dofactory.net/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx)

Hope this helps you to achieve your goal.

regards